# How should I handle Spiders/Web Crawlers using HTTP/0.9 if I am using Apache 2?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, apache2.2

I am using Apache 2 to serve content, and Bing Bot is using HTTP/0.9 to request pages from my server which does not serve direct IP hosts.

How should I handle the spider if I don't know which host they want, but still need them to index my site?

I currently return 400 Bad Request, but it makes me nervous that my sites will not be indexed for Bing or Yahoo.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> [SOLVED]: I have been returning 400 Bad Request and Bing/Yahoo have taken the hint.